# margin: auto not applicable to <img> elements with width property

Tags: html, css

Why margin: auto doesn't work with  elements if the width property can be specified for them? I know margin: auto does not apply to inline elements due to lack of width property. Why is like that in this case too?

Comment: margin:auto works with block elements (display:block,table,flex,grid,list-item, ...) and a width. -  Image has a width and is an inline element (phrasing content), it will only need a reset on display., else use text-align:center on the parent if the image stands alone in it

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, I have it more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Width has nothing to do with an img tag not being centered with margin: 0 auto.

It's because img have a default display of inline-block, so all you have to do is change the display property to block, then you can apply margin: 0 auto to it.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;  
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 300px; /* just for demo purposes */
  display: block; /* Remove this and margin: 0 auto won't work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I've read that width has something to do with margin: auto, since the margin has to be computed after knowing the width of the element.